# Is there a way to have a variable cell number in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I mean is can I do something like this:

```
IF([condition],A{1},A{1+n})
```

Where n is 1, for example, and then excel parses that as being cell A{2}.
Is that possible? Or at least something like it?

Comment: is `n` located in a cell?

Answer (score 5):

You can use INDEX():

```
=IF([condition],INDEX(A:A,1),INDEX(A:A,1+n))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to base `n` on another cell, you can use the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function in Excel to achieve this.

```
=IF([condition],A1,INDIRECT("A"&(1+F10)))
```

If the condition evaluates to `TRUE`, then it will use the value in A1. If it evaluates to `FALSE` and F10 is equal to 9, it will use the value in A10.

Answer (score 0):

***Variable Cell numbers can be used with other formula also:***

[image]

*Cell A9 =*

```
=IF(M1=2,AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH("Start",A:A,0) & ":" & "B" & MATCH("End",A:A,0))),0)
```

*Cell B10 =*

```
=If(M1=2,AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(INDEX(A:A,1),A:A,0) & ":" & "B" & MATCH(INDEX(A:A,2+2),A:A,0))),0)
```

Comment: You lost me on this one.  Can you clarify how it answers the question?

Comment: It's around the OP, and I'm trying to show that how Variable Cell references can be used in different way also. Like `MATCH(INDEX(A:A,2+2)`  similar to `INDEX(A:A,1+n))` shown in other answer.

Comment: @fixer1234, edited formula now it's conditional and  looking more relevant to the OP.